# Error using Quarto in R-markdown package - there is no package called rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I am getting a repeated error trying to Render a .qmd (Quarto) file:

```
Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘rmarkdown’
Calls: loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted

R installation:
  Version: 4.3.1
  Path: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
  LibPaths:
    - /usr/lib
    - /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library
  knitr: (None)
  rmarkdown: (None)

The rmarkdown package is not available in this R installation.
Install with install.packages("rmarkdown")
```

I have tried installing rmarkdown (latest version) multiple times:

```
Installing package into ‘/Users/DanielYudkin/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.3/rmarkdown_2.24.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2613591 bytes (2.5 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.5 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/sb/fll6frln7pqg42sztcn6z_4c0000gs/T//RtmpY9hwFP/downloaded_packages
```

Here are my details:

```
platform       aarch64-apple-darwin20      
arch           aarch64                     
os             darwin20                    
system         aarch64, darwin20           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          3.1                         
year           2023                        
month          06                          
day            16                          
svn rev        84548                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
nickname       Beagle Scouts
```

Comment: Quarto is looking for R packages in a different place that you are installing `rmarkdown`. Configure `R_LIBS` in your `~/.bashrc` to use your local installation.